# Display custom message with getty@.service disabled

Tags: centos8, rhel8

I have a CentOS 8 server running in a vm.  I access this server only via ssh.  Therefore I dont need the login prompt once server finishes booting up.  Therefore I went ahead disabling `getty@.service`.

Now server boots fine.  I can ssh to the server.

My ask is, how can I clear the screen and display a custom text once server finishes booting. The contents from /etc/issues is not loaded as I assume this file is read and used by `getty@.service`?  What options I have here?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading the man page of [agetty(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/agetty.8.html). I have never tried this, but this should work: Enable the service again, copy the service file to `/etc/systemd/system`, and modify it to start `/usr/sbin/nologin` instead of `/bin/login` ...

Exempt from the manpage:

> ```
>   -l, --login-program login_program
>       Invoke the specified login_program instead of /bin/login.
>       This allows the use of a non-standard login program. Such a
>       program could, for example, ask for a dial-up password or use
>       a different password file. See --login-options.
> ```

This way, the file /etc/issues is read and displayed, but a direct login on the terminal is not possible.  You might want to change the line `Restart=always` to `Restart=never`, to prevent a restart loop, but after that, you should be good to go.

But keep in mind, that no matter how you disable the getty service - if you ever loose network connectivity on your server (for example due to a configuration mistake), you'll have to boot a rescue disc in order to recover your server... It might not be a good idea to disable the getty service!

Comment: The article at this helped.  https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Run_software_on_tty1_console_instead_of_login_getty.html